# how to install dual boot on a new hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning

I am now installing a new hard drive in laptop; want to have dual boot. I know how to install Windows, and of course, I have installed Ubuntu a number of times, but I run into trouble understanding partitions. This is a new drive. What EXACT steps do I use to accomplish this? I am fearful because once partitions have been made, it seems impossible to change them. Exact steps would be appreciated, from the moment I have installed the hard drive, to turn the machine on.

Comment: Newer UEFI system or old BIOS? Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012, so most systems are UEFI, even if vendor may call UEFI as BIOS.You must install both systems in same boot mode and how you boot install media is then how it installs, so only boot in UEFI mode if newer system. Let Windows installer do its thing as it wants lots of partitions. Only if you want larger ESP, might you create that first. Then use Windows to shrink its NTFS partition and install Ubuntu into unallocated space.

Comment: There are many many tutorials on how to install Ubuntu. Partitions can almost ALWAYS be changed.

Comment: Partitions can appear impossible to change if you try to do it from the Ubuntu system installed on your laptop. Instead you should boot the Ubuntu installer, choose “Try Ubuntu” and run GParted from there. There are a few pitfalls though. It’s best to use Windows disk manager to make changes to Windows partitions especially if those changes alter the order or number of partitions on the disk. There are loads of answered questions on here about resizing partitions but you can always ask your own to provide specific details.

Comment: As @David has said there are plenty of tutorials online about dual boot installation, both written and on YouTube. You haven’t provided enough information for EXACT steps. We don’t know if the new hard drive is a replacement or an additional drive. We don’t know how big the drive is or how much space you want to allocate to each OS. Generally you should install Windows first and then Ubuntu. In the absence of any particular requirements just choose the “install alongside” option

Comment: Thanks, all. The computer is a 2017 Asus E5. I am installing a new 1T hard drive, and have UEFI set in the bios. So, I am hearing I should install Win10 as usual, and then go back in and re partition the HD (I want 300 gb for Win, and 700 gb for Ubuntu). And I should be able to do that in Window under disks? I am always scared to touch any partitions that  I see for fear of obliterating something. I should add that it had Win7 on it, I installed Ubuntu and had reset the Bios to legacy so had to switch it back.